# Problems with linebreaks while writing to a file

Tags: java, file

Hello im trying to write a file the problem is that when i open this file in the notepad look like this[image]

This is my java code:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ensamblador.asm");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
      {
          out.println("First Line);
          out.println("Second Line);
      } catch (IOException e) {}

  }
```

I tried this and still not working:

```
try(Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("ensamblador.asm"), "UTF-8")))
     {
         writer.write("First Line");
         writer.write("\n");
         writer.write("Second Line");
     }
     catch(IOException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I hope you guys can help me, thanks.

Comment: Are you on Windows by chance?  The line ending for that platform is `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Notepad only understands CR+LF pairs (aka `"\r\n"`) to be line terminators. A LF alone, which is the standard on Linux, will show like you see it. Are you running code on Linux? Because Java defaults to CR+LF when running on Windows. --- Suggest you use a better editor, e.g. Notepad++, which understands LF.

Comment: Yeah im running the code in the linux, the program generate the file and i open in virtual machine with Windows XP, the problem is that file that i generate from my java code is a asm code, so the sintaxys is strict

Comment: This is a common issue that is not restricted to Java. Any text file coming from Linux, when viewed in Windows Notepad, will exhibit this issue. The two operating systems use different line terminators. Almost all other text editors on Windows (such as Notepad++ which is free to download) will display Linux text files properly. It's a pity that Microsoft have not updated Notepad's behaviour since it was first released in the early 1990s.

Comment: @YosetGA As already mentioned, Linux line breaks are LF only, while Windows line breaks are CR+LF. Notepad is an old dumb program that doesn't understand Linux line breaks. You either need to convert file from Linux to Windows, or **use a better text editor**, e.g. Notepad++.

Comment: Even typing the file in Command Prompt displays it properly.

Answer (score 0):

In windows line separator is "\r\n".

But the better way is calling `br.newLine();` method. It will work for all platforms.

Comment: No, the problem is that OP [runs code on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637796/problems-with-linebreaks-while-writing-to-a-file#comment94135433_53637796) and then opens file on Windows, and expects the Linux line break to be correct on Windows.

Comment: yep you're right, it was not stated when I have posted the answer.